# R - Excel CSV lists of sentences - to array

Tags: arrays, r, csv

I have an excel sheet which has been converted to a csv. It has 5 rows of sentences with a header called questions. How do I convert the data.frame to an array so I can access it with lapply with my array.

Currently I can read and create the vector but cannot access it as an array it returns all elements.

How can this become an array?

```
> loremData <- read.csv("lorem.csv")
> head(loremData)
                                               Questions
1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur affectum elit.
2             Itaque contra est, ac dicitis consectetur;
3                Beatus sibi videtur esse moriens igitur
4                    naturam affectum esse possit Beatus
5         moriens consectetur. Quo igitur, inquit, modo?
> mydata <- c(loremData)
> head(mydata)
$Questions
[1] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur affectum elit.
[2] Itaque contra est, ac dicitis consectetur;            
[3] Beatus sibi videtur esse moriens igitur               
[4] naturam affectum esse possit Beatus                   
[5] moriens consectetur. Quo igitur, inquit, modo?        
5 Levels: Beatus sibi videtur esse moriens igitur ...

> mydata[1]
$Questions
[1] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur affectum elit.
[2] Itaque contra est, ac dicitis consectetur;            
[3] Beatus sibi videtur esse moriens igitur               
[4] naturam affectum esse possit Beatus                   
[5] moriens consectetur. Quo igitur, inquit, modo?        
5 Levels: Beatus sibi videtur esse moriens igitur ...
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean here. If you want to access individual questions, you can do that easily using the original data frame like `loremData$Questions[1]`. Or do you want to access individual words?

Comment: I want access to individual words. Ultimately to create a count of word occurrences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a reason for using

```
mydata <- c(loremData)
```

If you don't, you can use the loremData dataframe and read it row wise using the row number like

```
loremData[1,]
```

You can access it with lapply like this for example

```
lapply(seq_along(loremData), function(x) print(loremData[1,][x]))
```

for splitting as words (you will need to do more here to get rid of special characters like commas etc.)

```
a<-lapply(seq_along(loremData), function(x) strsplit(loremData[x],split='\\s+'))
```

You can get frequency count by

```
table(as.data.frame(a))
```

Comment: > words <- lapply(seq_along(loremData), function(x) strsplit(loremData[x],split = '\\s+'))
Error in strsplit(loremData[x], split = "\\s+") : non-character argument
Called from: strsplit(loremData[x], split = "\\s+")

Answer (score 1):

To put each individual word into a matrix you can use a function like `str_split` from the `stringr` package:

```
stringr::str_split(loremData$Questions, pattern = "\\s+", simplify = TRUE)
```

I can't guarantee that this will be efficient for large datasets though. You may want `simplify = FALSE` instead so that you don't get a matrix that's as wide as the longest sentence.